# verb matching after a word with a potential (s)

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which form is correct:

- Do you know where your Domain name(s) **are** registered?
- Do you know where your Domain name(s) **is** registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can go either way. See, for example, [When a sentence uses an optional plural, should the rest of the sentence treat it as singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11380/73553) on English.SE.

Personally, i would use the plural, as i read the sentence as including the S. Some people, however, prefer to treat the parentheses as optional and use the singular.

I think it also depends on which usage is more common. If the majority of people have only one domain, so it should be singular. If it will apply to most people in the plural, use the plural form.